# ASCII alternative to the Julia function composition (∘) operator?

Tags: julia, function-composition

Is there an ASCII alias for the function composition operator in Julia, `∘`?

In general, is there a way to find ASCII/Unicode variants of operators?

```
julia> ∘
∘ (generic function with 2 methods)
```

^Tried this, `≈` for example has an alternative:

```
julia> ≈
isapprox (generic function with 8 methods)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `∘` there is no alternative AFAICT. You can check by running:

```
julia> methods(∘)
# 3 methods for generic function "∘":
[1] ∘(f) in Base at operators.jl:874
[2] ∘(f, g) in Base at operators.jl:875
[3] ∘(f, g, h...) in Base at operators.jl:876
```

and opening the respective function definition (if you have a properly configured Julia installation just press e.g. <kbd>1</kbd> and then <kbd>CTRL-Q</kbd>) to get:

```
function ∘ end
∘(f) = f
∘(f, g) = (x...)->f(g(x...))
∘(f, g, h...) = ∘(f ∘ g, h...)
```

However, it is easy enough just to write:

```
const compose = ∘
```

and now you can use `compose(f, g)` instead of `f ∘ g`.

For `≈` and `isapprox` it is the case that in the code `isapprox` function is defined and then:

```
const ≈ = isapprox
```

definition is added in floatfuncs.jl.